# Adding a user to MongoDB (through RockMongo)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've got access to a database through the RockMongo UI. I want to be able to add other users that can login through this UI as well. I have found an option to add users per database, but that doesn't seem to do the trick (when I logout and try to login as the test-user, I get an authentication error). Anyone have any experience with this and can tell me how to achieve it (if it is possible)?

[image: screenshot]